# how to detect if PHPSESSID is changed

Tags: php, session

PHPSESSID Session Cookie

how to know if PHPSESSID is cahnged in the current session icouldn't find way to detect if this variable change is changes

as i want to check if the user has modfy the PHPSESSID or delete it (as deleteing it cause to create new one .)

and i can't save the value of this in session as all session are cleared when  i delete PHPSESSID 
and aslo idont want to save it in session cookie

Comment: I can think of a couple hacks to do this, but why would you want to?  What problem are you hoping to solve by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User (browser) can not change PHPSESSID, user can delete a cookie which stores session ID or modify URI parameter.
Why would your users modify/delete their session ID?

Comment: They can change it easily enough simply by editing their cookie (web developer toolbar for FF for example makes this really easy)

Comment: Yes, I meant they can't edit server variable, may be I've used wrong words :) But anyways, I don't see the reason to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

maybe he don't want to lose data in session

Answer (score 0):

To check PHPSESSID value(or any other cookie value) you can use firebug. There is a cookie tab in firebug and you can use it to examine or delete any cookie.

Using Firebug you can not modify cookie value. To modify cookie value, you can use "web developer toolbar" for firefox. It has a cookies tab through which you can add/modify/delete any cookie(including session cookie).